# Read CSV file column by column

Tags: java, csv, file-io, multiple-columns

I want to read specific columns from a multi column csv file and print those columns in other csv file using Java. Any help please? Following is my code to print each token line by line..But I am looking to print only few columns out of the multi column csv.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class ParseCSV {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try
        {

            //csv file containing data
            String strFile = "C:\\Users\\rsaluja\\CMS_Evaluation\\Drupal_12_08_27.csv";

            //create BufferedReader to read csv file
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(strFile));
            String strLine = "";
            StringTokenizer st = null;
            int lineNumber = 0, tokenNumber = 0;

            //read comma separated file line by line
            while( (strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                lineNumber++;

                //break comma separated line using ","
                st = new StringTokenizer(strLine, ",");

                while(st.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                //display csv values
                tokenNumber++;
                System.out.println("Line # " + lineNumber +
                                ", Token # " + tokenNumber
                                + ", Token : "+ st.nextToken());


                            System.out.println(cols[4]);
```

Comment: then only print out a few columns,and read (but skip) the ones you don't need...

Comment: Ugh. Java can use forward-slashes `/` for paths even on Windows `/Users/rsaluja/CMS_Eval...` so you don't have to double-up to escape the backslashes.

Comment: Yes could have used forward slashes ;)

Answer (score 54):

You should use the excellent [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) for reading and writing CSV files.  To adapt your example to use the library it would look like this:

```
public class ParseCSV {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      //csv file containing data
      String strFile = "C:/Users/rsaluja/CMS_Evaluation/Drupal_12_08_27.csv";
      CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(strFile));
      String [] nextLine;
      int lineNumber = 0;
      while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
        lineNumber++;
        System.out.println("Line # " + lineNumber);

        // nextLine[] is an array of values from the line
        System.out.println(nextLine[4] + "etc...");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 Agreed. Attempts to hack together some lines of code for parsing CSV data usually end in shouting and tears.  For CSV, use an API designed for the job.

Comment: Yes, Agreed. I could use Open Csv. But what I am looking for is I just need the selective columns. I have parsed the file correctly with all the tokens but it parses row by row, here I am looking for reading and then printing out only few selected specific columns. Thanks for the reply anyways! :)

Comment: *"But what I am looking for is I just need the selective columns."*  That in no way rules out using an API, so I am mystified as to why you started it with *"But.."*.

Comment: For the given requirement which require just to read specific columns from a CSV, no complex processing & no writing, wouldn't adding OpenCSV lib be an overkill? Just wondering...

Comment: This is obviously a personal opinion, but I would say it's not overkill because of how many external variables (the content of the CSV file) potentially threaten the stability of the program. For reference take a look at just the CSVReader source, because for the "weight" of the rest of the library OpenCSV is still doing a lot. The other consideration is the larger pursuit of keeping the code you write to a minimum count and a maximum expressiveness. Not everyone sees this as a goal but in my mind it is the only way to build sustainable systems.

Comment: Also see Joda-Time for another example of an "extra" library that aught to be in every project where a date is read, outputted or compared.

Answer (score 12):

Reading a CSV file in very **simple** and common in Java. You actually **don't** require to load any **extra** third party library to do this for you. CSV (comma separated value) file is just a normal plain-text file, store data in column by column, and split it by a separator (e.g comma ",").

In order to read specific columns from the CSV file, there are several ways. Simplest of all is as below:

**Code to read CSV without any 3rd party library**

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    // use comma as separator
    String[] cols = line.split(cvsSplitBy);
    System.out.println("Coulmn 4= " + cols[4] + " , Column 5=" + cols[5]);
}
```

If you notice, nothing *special* is performed here. It is just reading a text file, and spitting it by a separator – ",".

Consider an extract from legacy country CSV data at [GeoLite Free Downloadable Databases](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/geolite/)

```
"1.0.0.0","1.0.0.255","16777216","16777471","AU","Australia"
"1.0.1.0","1.0.3.255","16777472","16778239","CN","China"
"1.0.4.0","1.0.7.255","16778240","16779263","AU","Australia"
"1.0.8.0","1.0.15.255","16779264","16781311","CN","China"
"1.0.16.0","1.0.31.255","16781312","16785407","JP","Japan"
"1.0.32.0","1.0.63.255","16785408","16793599","CN","China"
"1.0.64.0","1.0.127.255","16793600","16809983","JP","Japan"
"1.0.128.0","1.0.255.255","16809984","16842751","TH","Thailand"
```

Above code will output as below:

```
Column 4= "AU" , Column 5="Australia"
Column 4= "CN" , Column 5="China"
Column 4= "AU" , Column 5="Australia"
Column 4= "CN" , Column 5="China"
Column 4= "JP" , Column 5="Japan"
Column 4= "CN" , Column 5="China"
Column 4= "JP" , Column 5="Japan"
Column 4= "TH" , Column 5="Thailand"
```

You can, in fact, `put` the columns in a `Map` and then get the values simply by using the `key`.

Shishir

Comment: That simple? Your example breaks when values have commas in them. E.g.
"1,0,0,0","1.0.0.255","16777216" would not work (but is a valid csv file). This is why using specifically designed apis can make your life easier, these edge cases have been thought of and (hopefully) tested.

Comment: I agree with @cowls

Comment: It depends on how well you know your system and use cases. When you know that the input CSV will not have edge cases, you do not need a library to read that through.

Comment: What is datatype for line here ?

Answer (score 6):

I am sorry, but none of these answers provide an optimal solution. If you use a library such as OpenCSV you will have to write a lot of code to handle special cases to extract information from specific columns.

For example, if you have rows with less columns than what you're after, you'll have to write a lot of code to handle it. Using the OpenCSV example:

```
  CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(strFile));
  String [] nextLine;
  while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
       //let's say you are interested in getting columns 20, 30, and 40
       String[] outputRow = new String[3];
       if(parsedRow.length < 40){
            outputRow[2] = null;
       } else {
            outputRow[2] = parsedRow[40]
       }
       if(parsedRow.length < 30){
            outputRow[1] = null;
       } else {
            outputRow[1] = parsedRow[30]
       }
       if(parsedRow.length < 20){
            outputRow[0] = null;
       } else {
            outputRow[0] = parsedRow[20]
       }

  }
```

This is a lot of code for a simple requirement. It gets worse if you are trying to get values of columns by name. You should use a more modern parser such as the one provided by [uniVocity-parsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers/).

To reliably and easily get the columns you want, simply write:

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.selectIndexes(20, 30, 40);
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(yourFile));
```

Disclosure: I am the author of this library. It's open-source and free (Apache V2.0 license).

Answer (score 2):

To read some specific column
I did something like this:

```
dpkcs.csv content:
FN,LN,EMAIL,CC
Name1,Lname1,email1@gmail.com,CC1
Nmae2,Lname2,email2r@gmail.com,CC2
```

The function to read it:

```
private void getEMailRecepientList() {
                List<EmailRecepientData> emailList = null;// Blank list of POJO class
                Scanner scanner = null;
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dpkcs.csv"));
                    Map<String, Integer> mailHeader = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                    // read file line by line
                    String line = null;
                    int index = 0;
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    // Get header from 1st row of csv
                    if (line != null) {
                        StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                        int headerCount = str.countTokens();
                        for (int i = 0; i < headerCount; i++) {
                            String headerKey = str.nextToken();
                            mailHeader.put(headerKey.toUpperCase(), new Integer(i));

                        }
                    }
                    emailList = new ArrayList<EmailRecepientData>();

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // POJO class for getter and setters
                        EmailRecepientData email = new EmailRecepientData();
                        scanner = new Scanner(line);
                        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
                    //Use Specific key to get value what u want
                        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                            String data = scanner.next();
                            if (index == mailHeader.get("EMAIL"))
                                email.setEmailId(data);
                            else if (index == mailHeader.get("FN"))
                                email.setFirstName(data);
                            else if (index == mailHeader.get("LN"))
                                email.setLastName(data);
                            else if (index == mailHeader.get("CC"))
                                email.setCouponCode(data);

                            index++;
                        }
                        index = 0;
                        emailList.add(email);
                    }
                    reader.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    StringWriter stack = new StringWriter();
                    e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(stack));

                } finally {
                    scanner.close();
                }

                System.out.println("list--" + emailList);

            }
```

The POJO Class:

```
public class EmailRecepientData {
    private String emailId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String couponCode;

    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getCouponCode() {
        return couponCode;
    }

    public void setCouponCode(String couponCode) {
        this.couponCode = couponCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Email Id=" + emailId + ", First Name=" + firstName + " ,"
                + " Last Name=" + lastName + ", Coupon Code=" + couponCode + "";
    }

}
```

Comment: Edit This part to get desired column of each row:                                                  else if (index == mailHeader.get("COULUM_NAME"))
                                syso(data)

Answer (score 1):

I sugges to use the Apache Commons CSV https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Here is one example:

```
    Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
    String currentPath = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    String csvFile = currentPath + "/pathInYourProject/test.csv";

    Reader in;
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = null;
    try
    {
        in = new FileReader(csvFile);
        records = CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader().parse(in); // header will be ignored
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (CSVRecord record : records) {
        String line = "";
        for ( int i=0; i < record.size(); i++)
        {
            if ( line == "" )
                line = line.concat(record.get(i));
            else
                line = line.concat("," + record.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println("read line: " + line);
    }
```

It automaticly recognize **,** and **"** but not **;** (maybe it can be configured...).

My example file is:

```
col1,col2,col3
val1,"val2",val3
"val4",val5
val6;val7;"val8"
```

And output is:

```
read line: val1,val2,val3
read line: val4,val5
read line: val6;val7;"val8"
```

Last line is considered like one value.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the core java stuff alone to read the CVS file column by column. Here is the sample code I have wrote for my requirement. I believe that it will help for some one.

```
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    String line = EMPTY;
    int lineNumber = 0;

    int productURIIndex = -1;
    int marketURIIndex = -1;
    int ingredientURIIndex = -1;
    int companyURIIndex = -1;

    // read comma separated file line by line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        lineNumber++;
        // use comma as line separator
        String[] splitStr = line.split(COMMA);
        int splittedStringLen = splitStr.length;

        // get the product title and uri column index by reading csv header
        // line
        if (lineNumber == 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < splittedStringLen; i++) {
                if (splitStr[i].equals(PRODUCTURI_TITLE)) {
                    productURIIndex = i;
                    System.out.println("product_uri index:" + productURIIndex);
                }

                if (splitStr[i].equals(MARKETURI_TITLE)) {
                    marketURIIndex = i;
                    System.out.println("marketURIIndex:" + marketURIIndex);
                }

                if (splitStr[i].equals(COMPANYURI_TITLE)) {
                    companyURIIndex = i;
                    System.out.println("companyURIIndex:" + companyURIIndex);
                }

                if (splitStr[i].equals(INGREDIENTURI_TITLE)) {
                    ingredientURIIndex = i;
                    System.out.println("ingredientURIIndex:" + ingredientURIIndex);
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (splitStr != null) {
                String conditionString = EMPTY;
                // avoiding arrayindexoutboundexception when the line
                // contains only ,,,,,,,,,,,,,
                for (String s : splitStr) {
                    conditionString = s;
                }
                if (!conditionString.equals(EMPTY)) {
                    if (productURIIndex != -1) {
                        productCVSUriList.add(splitStr[productURIIndex]);
                    }
                    if (companyURIIndex != -1) {
                        companyCVSUriList.add(splitStr[companyURIIndex]);
                    }
                    if (marketURIIndex != -1) {
                        marketCVSUriList.add(splitStr[marketURIIndex]);
                    }
                    if (ingredientURIIndex != -1) {
                        ingredientCVSUriList.add(splitStr[ingredientURIIndex]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finds all files in folder and write that data to ArrayList row.

Initialize

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> row=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
BufferedReader br=null;
```

For Accessing row

```
for(ArrayList<String> data:row){
data.get(col no); 
}
or row.get(0).get(0) // getting first row first col
```

Functions that reads all files from folders and concatenate them row.

```
static void readData(){
String path="C:\\Users\\Galaxy Computers\\Desktop\\Java project\\Nasdaq\\";
File files=new File(path);
String[] list=files.list();

try {
        String sCurrentLine;
       char check;
       for(String filename:list){ 
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path+filename));
        br.readLine();//If file contains uneccessary first line.
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

           row.add(splitLine(sCurrentLine));
        }
        }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


   static ArrayList<String> splitLine(String line){
   String[] ar=line.split(",");
   ArrayList<String> d=new ArrayList<String>();
   for(String data:ar){
    d.add(data);
   }

   return d; 
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, how about this !!

This code calculates both row and column count in a csv file. Try this out !!

```
    static int[] getRowsColsNo() {
    Scanner scanIn = null;
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    String InputLine = "";
    try {
        scanIn = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("filename.csv")));
        scanIn.useDelimiter(",");
        while (scanIn.hasNextLine()) {
            InputLine = scanIn.nextLine();
            String[] InArray = InputLine.split(",");
            rows++;
            cols = InArray.length;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return new int[] { rows, cols };
}
```

Comment: This approach will fail if the col value itself contains a comma.