# Reading a csv in Java

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv that I am trying to read into an array of objects. I keep getting the following error...
java.util.InputMismatchException
I think it is because its reading the file split by spaces and not by the commas. I believe I need to use the String.split() method, but I am not sure exactly how to do this. Any suggestions. Here is the code that I have thus far...

```
public class Prog7
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Part[] parts;
    int numParts;
    int partNumber;
    String description;
    double price;
    int quantity;
    String city;

    parts = new Part[100];
    numParts = 0;

    Scanner inFile = null;

    /*
     * open file
     */
    try
    {
        inFile = new Scanner( new File( "C:/COSC        210/Assignment#7/parts.txt" ) );
    }
    catch ( FileNotFoundException e )
    {
        System.err.println( "Error: file not found" );
    }

    /*
     * read file using each record to create a State object
     * and add that State object to the PopulationData object
     */
    while( inFile.hasNext() )
    {
        partNumber = inFile.nextInt();
        description = inFile.next();
        price = inFile.nextDouble();
        city = inFile.next();
        quantity = inFile.nextInt();


        Part p = new Part(partNumber, description, price, 
                          quantity, city);
        parts[numParts]= p;
        numParts++;

        for (int i = 0; i < numParts; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(parts[i].getPartNumber());
        }
    }
}
}
```

The following is the text file that I am working with:

```
12345,Left-Handed Bacon Stretcher,125.95,PGH,2

24680,Smoke Shifter,0.98,PGH,48

86420, Pre-dug Post Hole,2.49,ATL,34

25632,Acme Widget,98.29,LOU,342

97531,Anti-Gravity Turbine,895.29,ATL,3

24680,Battery-Powered Battery Charger,252.98,ATL,2

12345,Left-Handed Bacon Stretcher,125.95,LOU,35

97531,Anti-Gravity Turbine,895.29,PHL,8

00000,Glass Hammer,105.90,PGH,8

86420, Pre-dug Post Hole, 2.49,ATL,34

01020,Inflatable Dartboard,32.95,PGH,453

86420, Pre-dug Post Hole, 2.49,LOU,68

86420, Pre-dug Post Hole, 2.49,PGH,124

24680, Battery-Powered Battery Charger, 252.98, PHL, 5
```

Comment: assignment ? what is the content of the text file ?

Comment: Edit your question, Mike, don't put it as a comment.

Comment: Also my text file consists of a partNumber, Description, price, city, quantity. They are stored like the following...                                                             12345,Left-Handed Bacon Stretcher,125.95,PGH,2

Comment: Why don't you read each line using BufferedReader and then split it using a comma ?

Comment: take a look :     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169038/read-csv-file-column-by-column-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `scanner.useDelimiter(",");`

```
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File
                          ("C:/COSC        210/Assignment#7/parts.txt" ));
    inFile.useDelimiter(",");
    while (inFile.hasNext()) {
        int partNumber = Integer.parseInt(inFile.next());
        String description = inFile.next();
        double price = Double.parseDouble(inFile.next());
        String city = inFile.next();
        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(inFile.nextLine().replaceAll(",", ""));
        if(inFile.hasNextLine()) inFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(partNumber+","
                +description+","
                +price+","
                +city+","
                +quantity);
    }
    inFile.close();
```

Comment: I tried this, and it is still not working. I keep getting the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner by default uses whitespace as delimiter. Use `scanner.useDelimiter(",")` before reading the file.

Still its not fool proof as the content itself can have `","`

If its for learning then its fine otherwise you can look to use some library which already does this e.g. http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/files/opencsv/

Also instead of **fixed 100 length array** use **List** as if the records are more then hundred your code will break with exception.

Comment: where do I add scanner.useDelimiter(",")?

Comment: also not sure why you running the for loop after every record read. Probably you want to pull that out of while loop.