# How can I get column numbers in csv using buffered reader in java?

Tags: java, csv, bufferedreader

So here is what I am trying to do:

My csv has 5 columns

a b c d e

How can i get the column number of each column in the csv using java and also for that column using the column number I want to append data to the cell.I am new to this concept,so please suggest how I could move ahead.Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169038/read-csv-file-column-by-column-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String#split()` to process every line and collect the column values into an array. The (array index + 1) would give you the column number then or the value at column n would be at (n - 1) index.

```
String line = "a,b,c,d,e";
String[] values = line.split(",");

System.out.println ("Value at column 4 = " + values[3]);
```

Comment: My scenario is I am getting data from webservice now that web service can return only 2 value or 3 values...now based on the output if the value is this go and write this value in column 2 of csv file...any idea how to do that

Comment: Please add more info by posting relevant code and your use case into your question.