# Separate objects from a textfile to an Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm wondering how you would take info from a text file structured like the one below and write them to separate array lists.

```
human, parrot, salmon
dog, chicken, trout
rat, flamingo, goldfish
cat, cardinal, minnow
```

as you can see, above there are groups of Mammals, Birds and Fish! So I would declare these array lists as.

```
ArrayList<String> mammalList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> birdList = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> fishList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

the objective is to write the human, dog, rat and cat string objects to the mammalList. Then the birds to the birdList and the fish to the fishList.

I know how to read a text file using buffered reader to a single Array List but I'm stumped as to how I can separate each animal into their respective categories. Thanks so much for your help!

### -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

and here is the finished code that works correctly with Freestyle076's help :)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class testClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> mammalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> birdList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> fishList = new ArrayList<String>();

        BufferedReader read = null;

        try {   
            read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/animal_data.txt"));
            String str;
            while ((str = read.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] lineValues = str.split(" "); //split the string on spaces into array
                mammalList.add(lineValues[0].substring(0,lineValues[0].length() - 1)); //the mammal value, substring is to remove the comma
                birdList.add(lineValues[1].substring(0,lineValues[1].length() - 1)); //bird value, again substring to remove comma
                fishList.add(lineValues[2]); //fish value, no comma to remove
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (read != null) {
                try {
                    read.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        for(String mList:mammalList){
            System.out.println(mList);
        }


    }

}
```

It only prints the mammal list at the moment using an enhanced for loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read CSV file column by column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169038/read-csv-file-column-by-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could split each line on the spaces and append the mammal, bird and fish values to the mammal, bird and fish lists respectively.

```
String sCurrentLine;

br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("yourfilepath"));

while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] lineValues = sCurrentLine.split(" "); //split the string on spaces into array
    mammalList.add(lineValues[0].substring(0,lineValues[0].length() - 1)); //the mammal value, substring is to remove the comma
    birdList.add(lineValues[1].substring(0,lineValues[1].length() - 1)); //bird value, again substring to remove comma
    fishList.add(lineValues[2]); //fish value, no comma to remove
}
```

I am of course assuming that the arraylists have already been instantiated.

Also be wary on the fish value (listValues[2]), I don't recall if BufferedReader eliminates the new line character ('\n') for each read line. You may need to substring out the newline if it's still in the string after the readLine() call

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringTokenizer to break up the String by the commas. You know which position has which element, so just add them to the respective ArrayLists.

Answer (score 0):

You could try loading the file content to a string variable and splitting with the newline character into an array. Then split each line using comma. Since the data is structured like a db table, u can safely assume that index 0 on each line is for mammalList, 1 for d next & 2 for d last