# Reading multiple Variable types from a single line in java

Tags: java

So I have to read 5 file lines that appear as follows (in Java):

```
111 westwood street, Trafford, PA; 100000; 3; 1; 2000
222 southside lane, Pittsburgh, PA; 200000; 4; 2; 1500
```

I have to enter the data separated by semi colons as individual variables, ie `String address`; `int price`; etc.

How would I separate the `address`, `price`, `numbers of rooms`, etc. into different data types when reading from a file? The goal is to build a List of objects with each of these data as the constructor parameters.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Search: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+csv+parser

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read CSV file column by column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169038/read-csv-file-column-by-column)

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSV parser as suggested by others. However, if you want to do it by yourself, here is what you can do:

You can read each line as a String and then use the split() method to separate individual part from the line. Finally use methods like parseInt() to convert them to target data type. Here is an example of what you can do:

```
String line = "", street;
String[] parts;
int price;
File file = new File("your_file");
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    line = input.nextLine();
    parts = line.split(";");
    street = parts[0];
    price = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
    ...
}
input.close();
```

Of course, you have to use try-catch appropriately.