# How to get a value in a file with coordinates in Java

Tags: java, file, csv, line

My programm needs to read a file that has different data structures with a variable separator.
In my properties-file you can set the separator and put coordinates for values of different variables:

```
separator = ;
variable1 = 1,7
variable2 = 2,42
```

I would like to have a way where I can access a column and a line with some kind of coordinates.

I'm thinking of a syntax like this:

```
file.get(1,7,";")
```

(Which would give you the value of the 1st line and 7th column with the specific separator)
Does someone know a library or a code snippet that does exactly this?

Comment: `String.split()` is not suitable for (generic) CSV (RFC-4180), which can have quotes and escapes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169038/read-csv-file-column-by-column
Check if this helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `String.split()`  :

```
public String get(File file, int lineNumber, int column, String separator ) {
        //getting to the lineNumber of the file ommitted 
        // suppose you got it in a String named "line"
        return line.split(separator)[column - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/) or [SuperCSV](https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html) for example. I'm not aware of any library that does your 'coordinates' gettings, but it's as simple as reading the CSV with the given separator as `List`-of-`List`s and then call

```
csv.get(1).get(7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a simple file processing, You should first process the file -

- create `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` **processedFile**
- Read every line, split using `"line".split(separator)`
- Store the array above in the ArrayList **processedFile** at current index
- increase the index with every line

Once **processedFile** is ready, you can simply use `processedFile.get(row).get(column)`. Also once the file is processed, all the other queries will be **O(1)**. Hints are enough, try writing the code yourself, you will learn more.

PS: Take care of `NullPointerExceptions` wherever required.